# Exclude records in CSV file based on exclusion criteria in Config file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

The use case I am working on is to extract details from a command prompt the list of services running for a specific application such as Tableau, etc. The Output is usually in the below format

**File content in Tableau Services**

```
'Service 0' is running
'Service 1' is running
'Service 2' is running
'Service 3' is running
'Service 4' is running
'Test Service 5' is stopped
'SAML Service 6' is stopped
'Database Service 7' is stopped
'Tableau Service 8' is stopped
'Service 9' is running
'Service 10' is running
'Service 11' is running
'Service 12' is stopped
'Service 13' is running
'Service 14' is running
'Service 15' is stopped
```

**The final outcome should give the list of services that have stopped**

```
Service 12
Service 15
```

**Script**

```
 #EXTRACT THE CONTENTS FROM THE TABLEAU SERVICES
    $content = Get-Content 'C:\Tableau Services\TableauServices.txt'
    $content.replace("`t", "").Replace(" is ",",").replace(".","").Replace("'","").Trim() | select -Skip 2 | Out-File 'C:\Tableau Services\TableauServices.csv'
    
    $iRunningNumber=1
    #Extract Services which have Stopped
    Write-Host ("The List of Services that have stopped are as below: - ")
    Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Tableau Services\TableauServices.csv' `
                -delimiter ”,” `
                -Header ServiceName, Status | 
                    Where-Object {$_.ServiceName -notlike "*Test Service 5*" -AND $_.ServiceName - notlike "*SAML Service 6*" -AND $_.ServiceName -notlike "*Database Service 7*" -AND $_.ServiceName -notlike "*Tableau Service 8*"} | 
                     Select-Object ServiceName, Status |
                        Where-Object {$_.Status -match "Stopped*"} | 
                            ForEach-Object {"$($iRunningNumber).) $($_.ServiceName)"; $iRunningNumber++}
```

Currently, the Services to be excluded are hard-coded in the code. I would like to have these conditions extracted from a configuration file and then searched and excluded from the final list.

**I have another file which will contain the list of services to be ignored as below: -
SearchFile.txt**

```
Test Service 5
SAML Service 6
Database Service 7
Tableau Service 8
```

I have tried everything that I know of and still no solution. Request your help

Comment: Your code is creating a CSV file that you are reading. Where are the contents of that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

1. You don't need to create a csv file just to import it back right away. You can convert the csv data to an object directly by making use of `ConvertFrom-Csv`
2. The `-Raw` parameter when using `Get-Content` provide better perfomance than if not specified. It will however load your file as a single string. For that reason, I used it with `TableauServices` since we edited it as a single string and omitted it for `$ExcludeServicesConfig` since we needed the data as an array for the subsquent call `$ExcludeServicesConfig.Contains($Item.ServiceName)`
3. I refactored your code to use a `Foreach` loop instead of stuffing everything in a pipeline. That make debugging much easier later on if you have issues.

Ultimately, the key modifications is to check for each item whether or not it is part of the exclusion list and react accordingly.

Here's the code.

.

```
#EXTRACT THE CONTENTS FROM THE TABLEAU SERVICES
$content = Get-Content 'C:\Tableau Services\TableauServices.txt' -Raw
$ExludeServicesConfig = Get-Content -Path 'SearchFile.txt' 

$obj = $content.replace("`t", "").Replace(" is ", ",").replace(".", "").Replace("'", "").Trim() | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'ServiceName', 'Status'
    
$iRunningNumber = 1


#Extract Services which have Stopped
Write-Host ("The List of Services that have stopped are as below: - ")

Foreach ($item in $obj) {
    if ($ExludeServicesConfig.Contains($Item.serviceName)) { Continue }
    if ( $item.Status -eq "Stopped") {
        "$($iRunningNumber).) $($item.ServiceName)"
        $iRunningNumber += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with plain text files and they contain exactly what you have posted, you can do the following:

```
$Ignore = (Get-Content SearchFile.txt | Foreach-Object {
    [regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
(Get-Content TableauServices.txt) -notmatch $Ignore -match 'Stopped' -replace "^.*?'([^']+)'.*$",'$1'
```

**Explanation:**

Since `-match` and `-notmatch` use regex matching, you will need to create a regex friendly string. The `OR` equivalent in regex is `|`. For the items you want to ignore, we can join them using `|`. The point of `[regex]::Escape()` is to escape any special regex characters in your search string. Escaping tells regex to match literally.

`^` matches beginning of the string. `.*?` few characters as possible until the next character is matched (`'` in our case). `'` is a literal match of `'`. `[^']` is a negated (`^`) character class (`[]`) to match any character that is not `'`. `+` matches one or more of the previous character. `.*` matches zero or more characters greedily. `$` is the end of the string.

Since `-replace` has two parts, the first one that matches the string and the second one that acts as the replacement. Since we used `()` to group a match, that became a capture group (group `1` because it was the first set of `()`). You can reference capture groups in your replace string using the syntax `'$CaptureGroup'`, which would be `'$1'` in this case.

Comment: doesn't seem to work... 
Error Message
Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'notmatch'.
At line:3 char:76
+ ... TableauServices.txt" -notmatch $Ignore ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: You just need to have parentheses around your Get-Content command. I added that to this code.